# How transfer metadata from HTML to android auto

Tags: android

I have no idea, if the following task can be done with an HTML/PHP App.

My Audio-Player based on a HTML5 audio player works on an android phone, too. When I have the player running in my car, I can listen to the audio via Android Auto.
But I don't have any metadata, which will be displayed in the screen of the car, only the audio.
Is it possible with an generell, but modified HTML application (written in PHP) to send the audio metadata to Android Auto or would be this only possible with an native Android App?

If yes, how?

Thanks for you support!

Comment: If its written in PHP, I assume its a website you launched in a player of some sort?  If so, then no, it would be your player on the device that would need to implement that.

Comment: Gabe, that mean I have to write a Player for Android, right. So with an HTML application it is not possible!

Comment: I mean something on the device needs to play it.  That's either a browser, or some music player.  Now it's possible there's a player out there which will display like you want-  metadata can be embedded in most modern audio formats and a lot of players will display it if it's there.

Comment: Hi Gabe, let me try to clearify. I can receive on a Android phone a network radio stream with metadata and display it in the smartphone (HTML). Now if I do it inside my car and the radio with Android Auto is switched on, I can hear the sound of the HTML player cia BT on the radio. But is there any way also transmit the metadata from the HTML player via BT to Android Auto, or is for that a native Android App required? VLAN is transmitting also the metadata, but it is a real Android App.

Comment: Your phone doesn't receive anything.  An app on your phone does.  That app needs to work with Android Auto to display it, or you need another app.  There's nothing you're doing wrong on the server side, it's all about the client.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, sorry!. I wrote an HTML script, which is an client for my internet radio. This client playes the sound and also displays metadata like artist and title. It also displays the cover image f the smart phone. So that is fine. If somebody is using this HTML player and has connected the phone via Bluethoot and Android Auto to the car radio, the sound will come out of the car speakers.       => What I need is an answer, is it possible for an pure HTML application (not an Android app) to send metadata to Android Auto and this information will be displayed on the car screen?

Comment: Right-  that's not how it happens.  There is a piece of software on the phone that plays music.  That piece of software is an app.  THat app can be any one of hundreds of music players.  WHatever one they're using-  that's what has to talk to Android Auto.  Not your server.  Your server can do nothing if its already serving the metadata.  It's the client side player that does it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and this is how I solved it! I used the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API). It allows you to send metadata to smart devices such as car radios, smart watches, the volume control on windows commuters, and more. I used this API when working on a radio website to display metadata when listening in the car. [Check it out](https://www.881theburg.com/burg2) to see if this is similar to what you are trying to accomplish!

I used some JavaScript in my HTML to change the Title, artist, and cover photo:

```
if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
        title: TitleName,
        artist: ArtistName,
        artwork: [
            { src: ImgLocation,   sizes: '75x75',   type: 'image/png' },
            { src: ImgLocation, sizes: '500x500', type: 'image/png' },
            { src: ImgLocation, sizes: '1080x1080', type: 'image/png' },
        ]
    });
}
```

TitleName, ArtistName, and ImgLocation are all variables.

Depending on how you are getting you metadata for your live audio, we are using xml files, you may need to write some JavaScript to get the metadata.

[This](https://web.dev/media-session/) is one of the websites I used to understand the MediaSession API.

This is what my app looks like when playing music:

[image: My App Showing Metadata on the page]

and this is what my app looks like when metadata is inputted in the MediaSession API:

[image: Metadata for closed app on phone]

All the information above is also given to radios when connecting over bluetooth:
[image: Metadata on radio in car]

I have not tested this with Android Auto but the same should be true.

Give this a try and post your code if you get stuck!